# Javascript show div when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I realize that this is a common question and I have searched for solutions and the one that I'm trying to use (it works in jsfiddle) but when I tried to use it in my website it just won't work.  I'm trying to show a div when a button is clicked.  Am I doing something wrong?  Maybe there's something wrong with the javascript?  Or could it be I need to include a jquery js file?  Thanks for your help in advance.

Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#seeAnswer").click(function() {
    $('#subtext').html($(this).next().html());
  });
</script>
```

And I'm trying to use it with this:

```
<div class="back_button">
  <button id="seeAnswer">See Answer</button>
</div>
<span>
  <?php 
    /*  foreach($row2 as $ans) {
           $answer = $ans['answer'];
            }
   echo $answer;
   echo "hi";
  */
?>

    <?php foreach ($row2 as $ans) : ?>
        <p><?php htmlspecialchars($ans['answer']) ?></p>
    <?php endforeach ?>
      <p>hi there</p>
</span>

<div id="subtext">
</div>
```

Comment: In regards to: "Or could it be I need to include a jquery js file?" You do need to load jQuery... I'm guessing you already do that in the <HEAD> right... before your own code...

Comment: Okay, here is what my <HEAD> looks like `<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#seeAnswer").click(function () {
    $('#subtext').html($(this).parent().next().html());
});
</script>

</head>`

Comment: The problem is that the DOM is not completely loaded... i will update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.parent()` after `.next()` because you are referring to the next element after the button... but there is no element... so you want the `next()` of the parent element.

**EDIT:** as per new information about the `<HEAD>`, you are executing the code before the whole dom is ready... so you're actually applying the code to nothing. You need to wait for the DOM to be ready. Like this

```
$('docment').ready(function() {
    $("#seeAnswer").click(function () {
        $('#subtext').html($(this).parent().next().html());
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RVB4R/)

Comment: @user3272438 then the problem seems to be elsewhere. Look at the fiddle and you will see it's working. Do you have multiple buttons with "seeAnswer" as the ID? Remember, element id's must be unique.

Comment: I see it is working and I'm lost as to why mine won't work... I only have one button with the ID as "seeAnswer"

Comment: Okay now it works, thank you so much, I got it to work with the information from the database

Comment: It's probably related to something else. Can you confirm that what should come from the database is actually written in the <span>?